# Rollback a single file in TFS

Tags: tfs

If I view the history of a single file in source control I can right hand click a change-set in the list and choose "rollback back entire change-set".

Will this rollback all the other files I checked in during that checkin or just the file I am currently viewing? If it does rollback all files is there a way to rollback just the file selected?

Thanks

Answer (score 98, accepted):

As previously mentioned, rolling back the changeset rolls it back in its entirety.

Installing **Team Foundation Power Tools** (which I think pretty much everyone should install) gives you another option: If you want to rollback a single file, you can right click a single file in the Source Control Explorer and select **Rollback...**

Comment: This is actually a better answer

Comment: Glad to help. You can also use the command line (`tf.exe`) to perform the rollback on a single file.

Comment: Download for Visual Studio 2010 integration: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f

Comment: In newer versions of TFS, this is native functionality, so check before installing Power Tools

Comment: @Aaroninus What is it called in newer versions/where to find it?

Comment: @LJNielsenDk It's the same way as described in the answer, just without the need for Power Tools (right-click file in Source Control Explorer)

Answer (score 40):

Yes, rolling back the entire changeset will roll back all the changes in it.

However, a Rollback is not instant, when you click that option the rollback will be perform a reverse merge and leave the changes in your workspace. So you can look at them in Pending Changes.

In your case, just perform the Rollback and then undo everything except the file you actually want to Rollback.

Comment: This normally works, but not if one of the other files that you don't need to rollback is locked by another user.

Answer (score 28):

From now on, in visual studio 2015 atleast, you can just go to source control, right click a file and choose Rollback.. This will ask you what changeset you would like to rollback for this file and it will only rollback that file.

Comment: This also applies to Team Explorer Everywhere TFS plugin for Eclipse (only checked on v14)

Comment: This option doesn't exist for me in Solution Explorer. Either on the primary right click menu or under "Source Control" submenu

Comment: If you are reading this in 2019 I would suggest switching your repo to using git, there are tools available to copy the tfs check-ins history.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple workaround :)
1. rollback entire changeset
2. undo all file except file you actually want.

Comment: ATTENTION: Don't do this if you have already files checked-out. This will create a huge mess in your workflow. I lost work because I had some files checked-out, then some files were the same as the ones I rolled back, and when I did Undo changes, I unintentionally undid my local changes previous to the rollback. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you click on rollback the entire changeset, it will check out all of the items in the changeset to be rolled back. Then just go and undo checkout all other files that don't want to be rolled back. Then just check in the files you want to be rolled back.