# TFS 2010: GetThisVersion works but files don't show in View Pending Changes

Tags: tfs

Using TFS 2010

I am going back to the previous versions of several files across various projects(all of these were previously rolled back)
To do this, I View History on the project, and choose GetThisVersion.
This works fine.

I now want to see a list of all the files for which I have a previous version.
I expected these to show up in the View Pending Changes. But they don't. Why is that?

Do I have to explicitly check out the file first, and then go to a previous version?

Comment: What is the goal of getting the previous version? Do you want to roll the files back to a previous version? This way, the files are checked out, you can see them in pending changes and you can check them in again as the latest version. Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420165/rollback-a-single-file-in-tfs

Comment: Markus,
Yes. I want to roll certain files back to a previous version. This linked helped. DOH. WE made changes(changeset#1), then rolled all of them back(changeset#2) because of a problem. I was looking at changeset#1 and reverting the files. Instead I should go to changeset#2 and simply rollit back. Thanks, helped me see the light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a file from the server (whichever version - latest or specific) doesn't check out the file. You have to check it out explicitely.

Depending on the options you have switched on ("Get latest version of item on checkout"), checking out a file may get the latest version at the same time. In this case, you may have to:

- get a specific version first,
- copy the files locally outside of TFS folders,
- check out files and replace with the specific version.

Comment: >>Getting a file from the server (whichever version - latest or specific) doesn't check out the file.>>> That makes sense. Thanks